# Sqlite3 Updating Row Defined by a Variable

Tags: python, sqlite

Not sure if I phrased the title correctly, but basically my question is is it possible to have sqlite update a row which is defined by a variable? For example:

```
db.execute('''UPDATE CUSTOMER SET ? = ? WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?''', (title, info.get(), k))
```

where 'title' (the first question mark) is the name of the 'row' I want to update within the table Customer. I have tried the above code but it doesn't work. Does anybody know if it is possible to do this with sqlite3 in any way?

Comment: it is possible, did you commit it?

Comment: I did commit it and when I tried to run it got the error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

Answer (score 3):

SQL parameters are designed to *never* be interpretable as SQL objects (like column names); that is one of their major usecases. If they didn't they wouldn't prevent SQL injection attacks. Instead, the `title` value is either properly escaped as a *value*, or rejected altogether as the syntax doesn't allow a value in that location.

As such, you need to make sure that your `title` variable is a proper SQL object name (**never** take user input directly here) and use string formatting for *just that value*:

```
db.execute(
    '''UPDATE CUSTOMER SET {} = ? WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?'''.format(title),
    (info.get(), k))
```

You probably want to match `title` against a pre-defined set of possible column names first.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this

```
query = "UPDATE CUSTOMER SET %s = '%s' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = %d" %(title, info.get(), k)
db.execute(query)
```

May be you need to `commit` it.