# sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

Firstly, I know that there are already posts on here with the similar titles, I have looked at the answers to those questions but still can't figure out a solution from those answers. (My problem is slightly different to the rest).

I need to be able to update the value of a field for a specific record in my sqlite database. One of the posts I have used to help me with this problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335050/sqlite3-updating-row-defined-by-a-variable).

I have used the same formatting in my code here:

```
updateCustomerTable = c.execute("UPDATE customerTable SET {} = ? WHERE customerID = ?").format(age), (newAge.get(),) , (customerID.get(),)
```

but I am getting an error message:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"
```

Why is the curly bracket not allowed when the developer has used it in the answer for the other post?

Answer (score 2):

Here (code reformated for readability):

```
c.execute(
    "UPDATE customerTable SET {} = ? WHERE customerID = ?"
    ).format(age)
```

so in fact you are calling `.format()` on the result of `c.execute()`, not on your SQL query string. It would actually raise an `AttributeError` if the query was valid SQL FWIW.

What you want is:

```
sql = "UPDATE customerTable SET {} = ? WHERE customerID = ?".format(age)  
c.execute(sql, ...)
```

Comment: I've put the arguments in that retrieve the results into the execute line, so c.execute(sql, (newAge.get(),) , (customerID.get(),))   but that means there's 3 arguments where 2 are given? Am i supposed to put something else into that line?

Comment: Is this question resolved? As noted, the `.format()` method must be operated on string statement with query parameters passed in one additional argument as either list or tuple.