# UPDATE together with the WHERE statement with variables in sqlite and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am coding with python and using SQLite. I need to update a table using the UPDATE and WHERE statements. The challenge is that both values for the WHERE and UPDATE statements must be variables. I have done some research and found this link [Sqlite3 Updating Row Defined by a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335050/sqlite3-updating-row-defined-by-a-variable) and this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

```
def studentlist():
    '''Checks if a student is checked in any class, inserts the status into the
    student list table Displays a list of all students and their class status'''
    c.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM StudentTable")
    all_students = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM CheckedInTable")
    selected_student_id = c.fetchall()
    print("The student id in the studentlist is:", selected_student_id,)
    for i in all_students:
        if i in selected_student_id:
            student_attendance = 'Attending a class'
            c.execute("UPDATE StudentlistTable set ClassAttend = ?", (student_attendance), "WHERE StudentID = ?", (i))
            conn.commit()
        else:
            student_attendance = "Not in class"
            c.execute("UPDATE StudentlistTable set ClassAttend = ?", (student_attendance))
            conn.commit()
studentlist()
```

Upon running the code, I receive the following error

```
c.execute("UPDATE StudentlistTable set ClassAttend = ?", (student_attendance), "WHERE StudentID = ?", (i))
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the actual UPDATE query which is being run?  Off the top of my head, there could be a problem with your data such that the query is not doing what you expect.

Comment: The i were empty tuples instead of actual values. Converting every i to an appropriate string variable worked as desired. @ Tim thanks

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum; do not change the question in a way that can invalidate existing answers. Your question has been answered; if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message you are receiving, the `execute()` function is expecting 2 arguments, the first for the query and the second a single tuple containing the parameters to be used in the query.  Try this:

```
c.execute("UPDATE StudentlistTable SET ClassAttend = ? WHERE StudentID = ?",
          (student_attendance, i))
```

Here is a good reference question which discusses your problem in greater detail:

[How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: This answer eliminates the error i.e the entire code runs without returning any error but the update statement does not change the table as anticipated

Comment: Can you provide more information.  What is unexpected?

Comment: For ease of use click on the edited(some time) ago link, in order to follow through all the edits.